# Java - is it bad practice not to have a class constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, helper

I want to make a helper class that deals with formatting (i.e. has methods to remove punctuation and convert between types, as well as reformatting names etc.). This doesn't seem like it will need any fields - its only purpose is to get passed things to convert and return them, reformatted. Is it bad practice to leave out a constructor? If so, what should my constructor be doing? I was looking at [this link](http://myprogrammingblog.com/2013/03/22/java-helper-class-bmi-calculator-lb-to-kg-converter-kg-to-lb-converter-feet-to-cm-converter-cm-to-feet-converter/) and noticed that the class it describes lacks a constructor.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to leave out a constructor?

Yes - because unless you specify *any* constructors, the Java compiler will give you a constructor with the same visibility as the class itself.

Assuming all your methods are static - which seems likely unless you want polymorphism - you should make your class `final` and give it a `private` constructor, so that other developers don't *accidentally* create an instance of your class, when that would be pointless. When thinking about an API, any time I can remove the ability for developers to do something stupid, I do so :)

So something like:

```
public final class Helpers {
    private Helpers() {
    }

    public static String formatDate(Date date) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Note that by taking polymorphism out of the equation, you're also removing the possibility of changing this behaviour for tests etc. That may well be fine - I'm not a believer in "no statics, ever" - but it's worth considering.

Comment: thank! I've never (in my very brief experience with Java) seen a private constructor before, so that's interesting and helpful too.

Comment: Not sure if anyone will see this, but I have another question. I implemented this solution, and now, somewhere in my code, need a method that formats Employee data for output as a string(sent later to stdout). Does it make sense to put it in this utility class when it is probably only going to be needed for use with Employee objects, rather than having general purpose?

Comment: @FalseAzure: If you have another question, you should post it as another question. Don't just add it as a comment to an existing question or answer.

Answer (score 6):

Any class that has all the methods which do not have or need any state is *free to reduce the visibility of constructor by making the constructor private.*

**Example [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class in Java.**

As `java.lang.Math` has *all static methods* which do similar job as your class they have declared the constructor as `private` so that nobody can accidentally create the instance of that class.

```
    /**
     * Don't let anyone instantiate this class.
     */
    private Math() {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not bad practice. but the example that you have given doesn't have any member variables that can be used in an Object context. In such situations, it's best to have static methods because then you don't need to allocate memory to create objects for the class before calling the methods.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler will generate a default constructor (with no parameters) for you. If your class has not state and does not extend a class which needs initialization, you can let it without declaring explicit constructor

Answer (score 1):

no its good to leave out a constructor as there aren't any instance variables in your class!

constructors are meant to initialize the instance variables!

still if you skip the constructor, compiler anyways inserts the default constructor which is fair enough!!

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor.

[Java Official Document: Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Answer (score -2):

Usually it is a good coding practice to define your constructor in the class though each class has a default constructor .

But if you do not have any special need to use a oveloaded constructor or to make any singleton pattern then you can remove the constructor .

If you are using static methods in your case then also you dont have any need to define constructor , as you do not need to have object of this class .